# VBA to Lock one Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to lock J7 from being edited but can't seem to get the code right to do so. Any suggestions as to how I may adjust the Worksheet selection change code below would be appreciated!

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G26:BA9999")) Is Nothing And Range("G" & Target.Row).Value <> Empty Then
    Range("B2").Value = Target.Row
    Initiative_Load

End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L17,L19,U3,U5,U7,U9,U11,U13,U15,U17,U19,U21")) Is Nothing Then
    CalendarFrm.Show

End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J7")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("J7").Locked = True

End If

End
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: use `CountLarge`: `If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub`. It's safer than `.Count`.

Comment: Another side note: `Range("G" & Target.Row)` is equivalent to `Target` in this case, because `Target` is only one cell and intersects column G.

Comment: There is no use of locking a cell, if you don't protect the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

In general:

1. Insure the worksheet is **un-protected.**
2. Adjust the Lock/Unlock status of a cell or group of cells.
3. **Re-protect** the worksheet.

```
Sub Lock_J7()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="secret"
        Cells.Locked = False
        Range("J7").Locked = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password = "secret"
End Sub
```